# Chunk in knitr fails to compile in latex; shaded rows of xtable

Tags: r, compiler-errors, latex, knitr, xtable

This is a chunk in knitr. It fails to compile in latex, although the chunk itself runs and gives me a table that (perhaps naievely) looks OK?

```
<<results_A549_rate, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
library(xtable)
end_table<-matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=5)
rws<-seq(from=1, to=dim(end_table)[1], by=2)
cols<-rep(c("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}"), length(rws))
x_endtable<-xtable(end_table, caption="Rate changes", digits=3, label="table_A549")
print(x_endtable, booktabs=TRUE, add.to.row=list(pos=as.list(rws), command=cols)) 
@
```

Comment: did you add booktabs to the packages used in the preamble ?